# How to extract substrings from a string in java

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

I am not so confident in Java so I need some help to extract multiple substrings from a string.string is as given below.

I have a text file with possibly thousands of similar POS-tagged lines that I need to extract the original text from that.I have tried using tokenizer but didn't really get the result I wanted.I tried using Pattern Matcher and I am having problems with the regex.

```
String="I_PRP recently_RB purchased_VBD this_DT camera_NN";
```

I want to get the output= I recently purchased this camera.

I use

Regex: `[\/](.*?)\s\b`

But its not working.Please help me.

Comment: Show us an actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please. And clarify what the problem is. "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    String s= "I_PRP recently_RB purchased_VBD this_DT camera_NN";
    s = s.replaceAll("_\\w+(?=(\\s|$))", "");
    System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
I recently purchased this camera
```

Comment: thanks for the response,I am having a bit more trouble.This code is working for a single string.But when i take a text file as an input file using FileReader and BufferdReader that time it is not showing any result in outputfile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are attaching a tag to indicate the word type (e.g. noun, verb or pronoun) if this suffix will be always capital letters, it is more safe to use the following regex in your `replaceAll`

```
s = s.replaceAll("_[A-Z]+(?=(\\s|$))", "");
```